# anyone running Mtink successfully on 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I've spent 2 hours trying to make mtink work on 20.04.  It appears that Epson has dropped Epson-Printer-Utility -cannot download it.  I'm looking for confirmation that it is possible, someone is actually running it.

If so, second question is how did you connect to Epson printer not on list?

Comment: »» connect to Epson printer not listed «« : Depends which printer it's about. Please edit your question https://askubuntu.com/posts/1357217/edit to include Epson version.

Comment: it doesn't matter which Epson not-on-list printer. It  would be helpful to be one not-on-list so that answerer can share how it was done.  To name my printer would be too limiting.  I am very skeptical that anyone is actually running this application in 20.04.  Who knows?  Maybe we'll find out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cups doesn't use usblp module anymore and mtink needs it. You can load that module manually, then use mtink, and finally unload it.

This is what works for me for my Epson C62 on 20.04.

Terminal commands:
sudo modprobe usblp
sudo mtink

(You may need to switch the printer off and then on again for this to work).

When you have finished using your printer type:

sudo modprobe -r usblp

N.B. you must type the “sudo modprobe -r usblp” after you have finished using the mtink printer utility and exited the application to unload the usblp module. You must unload the usblp module otherwise printing documents will be affected.